# git attribute using filter smudge/clean to process .cpp files through shell script not finding filename

Tags: git, attributes, format

I wanted to setup code style formatting for all .cpp files before they are committed to git.

I made small script (named codeformat) to do this, (also tried replaing %f with $1)

```
#! /bin/bash
clang-format -style=file %f | diff %f -**
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "ERROR: codeformat not correct"
   exit 1
fi
```

did setup git config and updated .gitattributes with *.cpp  filter=codeformat,

```
git config --global filter.codeformat.clean codeformat
git config --global filter.codeformat.smudge codeformat
```

looks like script is being run, but it is not getting file name. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `%f` directive in the wrong place.

As shown in [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) (search for `%f`):

> Sequence "%f" on the filter command line is replaced with the name of the file the filter is working on. A filter might use this in keyword substitution. For example:
>
> ```
> [filter "p4"]
>         clean = git-p4-filter --clean %f
>         smudge = git-p4-filter --smudge %f
> ```

Hence, to get the path name of the file, you would need to set, e.g., `filter.codeformat.clean` to `codeformat %f`.

At this point you will also need to modify your bash script, since *its* syntax for argument substitution is indeed `$1`.  However, read the immediate next paragraph from the gitattributes documentation:

> Note that "%f" is the name of the path that is being worked on. **Depending on the version that is being filtered, the corresponding file on disk may not exist, or may have different contents.** So, smudge and clean commands should not try to access the file on disk, but only act as filters on the content provided to them on standard input.

The emphasis here is mine, but this is telling you that you cannot simply open the disk file and read it.  You must filter only the standard input, providing standard output.

([As it turns out, clang-format is designed to do just that.](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)  Diff, however, is not.)

---

Edit to add working example:

```
$ cat ~/scripts/dotest
#! /bin/sh
echo "dotest run with $# arguments:" >>/tmp/dotest_log
for i do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done >>/tmp/dotest_log
cat
$ which dotest
[path edited]/scripts/dotest
$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[filter "testfilter"]
        clean = dotest %f
        smudge = dotest %f
$ cat .gitattributes
*.test  filter=testfilter
$ echo 'bar.test' > bar.test
$ git add bar.test
$ cat /tmp/dotest_log
dotest run with 1 arguments:
bar.test
```

Comment: See added working example. I don't know what you have done differently, but my script is called with the file name, as shown in the log file in /tmp.

Comment: this helps, earlier i missed to run git config, i did run git config --global, but i have to run "git config" alone without global to get it update in .git/config otherwise it only updates in ~/.gitconfig. now, its printing the filename , i need to play with my code format command now.

Comment: can we write error messages to screen?, let us say content from /tmp/dotest_log, wehn i trigger git add? i have some echo commands instead redirecting to log, it doesn't write log, it only gives message error  filter...objective is to give some message so user can follow, furthermore, exit inside script is not exiting git operations, my git add is still succeeding even-though script failed, can we force it to fail git add too until they fix ?

Comment: The filter's stderr is connected to Git's stderr, so writing to stderr may or may not write to a terminal. However, the exit status of the filter is ignored *unless* it is marked `required`, in which case if the filter exits nonzero, Git declares that the conversion failed and therefore the entire operation (`git add` or index-to-worktree checkout) failed as well. Note that the entire protocol is fairly different if you write a (more complex) *process* filter; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).

Comment: yes, required = true is doing, but its triggering smudge too even thought i don't have smudge filter in my config. can i apply required alone to clean? it means, don't trigger smudge at all.

Comment: @Ramana: *can i apply required alone to clean* No, it's all-or-nothing. The newfangled process protocol might be more useful here, but is harder to work with.

Answer (score 0):

`%f` is interpreted by `git` and should be in `gitconfig`. In the shell script use `$1`:

```
git config --global filter.codeformat.clean 'codeformat %f'
git config --global filter.codeformat.smudge 'codeformat %f'

#! /bin/bash
clang-format -style=file $1 | diff $1 -**
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "ERROR: codeformat not correct"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I tried that too, didn't help, please see below more details.

Answer (score -1):

that means, i can never get file name?, i tried %f with git config itself and changed script to use $1, still it doesn't get filename.

```
cat ~/.gitconfig

 [filter "codeformat"]
         clean = codeformat %f
         smudge = codeformat %f

cat .gitattributes
    #clang code style format
    *.cpp                           filter=codeformat

 cat codeformat
    #! /bin/bash
    clang-format -i -style=file $1 -
    echo "file/path accessed is _____ $1 ____" > log_output 2>&1

git add src/sample.cpp

    cat log_output
    file/path accessed is _____  ____
```

same command(below) if i run on command line works well,

```
clang-format -i -style=file src/sample.cpp
```

With git add it cannot get filename and hence other error with 
*error: cannot use -i when reading from stdin.*

note this time, i removed diff command, used -i to replace source file directly"