# Using git, how to auto-format when pull/clone/fetching from github

Tags: git, github, code-formatting

OK, so our team is new and we're working on determining a style guide for our code. We are a GoLang shop, so formatting that is simple.

Shell script code (among many) don't have a single canonical style guide by which to go.

We will use `shfmt` (because it's seemingly decent) in a commit hook, which will at least keep our code style homogenous in the repo. But what about some way of being able to "bend" the code back from the homogenous style by `shfmt` to our individual styles? Does something like that exist?

I guess I could just use `shfmt` or one of the other 10-odd tools out there that "beautify" shell-code and configure that tool to the closest settings possible to get back my style. That is a likely direction in which I'll need to go.

Two questions:

1. anyone know of a tool that can go foward or backward in formatting?
2. What about an auto-clone/pull/fetch hook or way that would do this automatically?

Obviously, I can write a wrapper script that I exec after a pull, but just wondering if anyone has ever done anything like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not be a practical approach ("forward or backward in formatting"), because it involves rewriting the commits (changing their content, hence their SHA1)

The usual approach is simply to refuse any pushed commit, if its shfmt output differ from the commit content pushed (meaning the code was not properly formatted *before* pushing.

Still, should you want to make sure that past commits are formatted, you would use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), as described in "[Reformatting Your Codebase with git filter-branch](http://elliot.land/post/reformatting-your-codebase-with-git-filter-branch)" by [**Elliot Chance**](https://twitter.com/elliotchance).

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'shfmt $(\
  git show $GIT_COMMIT --name-status | egrep ^[AM] |\
    grep .sh| cut -f2)' -- --all
```

However, all developer would need to reset his/her local clone to the new rewritten repo.

> I'm simply seeking a way to display my style in my local repo.

The issue is to display your style *while* not changing the content.
You can try a [smudge/clean content filter approach as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46857762/6309).

Comment: Well, as far as a forward approach, that would be done in a pre-commit hook, so there'd be no rewriting the commit per se (I thought pre-commit hooks worked before the SHA). I see your point for the backward formatting and it is something I was aware of when I asked the question. Essentially, I'm simply seeking a way to display my style in my local repo. I admit, it seems difficult and probably not practical, but I just wanted to see if anyone else has attempted to do this. The method you describe is likely something I will look at, but for different reasons.

Comment: @Jim a pre-commit hook can easily be bypassed (or not installed, or un-installed). A pre-receive hook on the server side is more effective to enforce a policy.

Comment: @Jim I have edited the answer to add an alternative (content filter driver)

Comment: I've been googling over it. I ultimately believe you're right, but am thinking about it a little differently now while reading over https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6687600. The answer is not in the VCS. It's in the editor (or a wrapper before the editor) to convert code to my likes and then convert back to the team standard before and after editing respectively. I'm going to look around for a tool that does that. If I can't find it, maybe I'll write one.

Comment: @Jim " It's in the editor (or a wrapper before the editor) to convert code to my likes and then convert back to the team standard ": yes, that is what smudge/clean scripts are designed to do, automatically on checkout/commit. But you still need to find the right tool for those scripts to call.